# Dockerized PostgreSQL image: where to access CSV file to give as input?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a dockerized Postgres container that I can manipulate from the shell using psql. I would like to fill the `cities` table from a CSV file:

```
\copy cities(location, latitude, longitude) FROM 'postgis.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV HEADER;
```

However, this command returns "postgis.csv: No such file or directory". How can I do the above in Docker and PostgreSQL? I've tried editing my docker compose file by adding

```
volumes:
  - ./src/db/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

And now I have the database data folder locally, but not sure where I should put the CSV file. Sorry for the noob question.

Comment: does your local `./src/db/pgdata` folder contains this csv file? if so, what about `copy cities(location, latitude, longitude) FROM '/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgis.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV HEADER;`

Comment: How is the question programming-related? The question might be better suited for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Thanks a lot @ItayB! That worked. Maybe I can flag so that a mod can move this to the appropriate site. Apologies for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does your local `./src/db/pgdata` folder contains this csv file?

if so, what about

`copy cities(location, latitude, longitude) FROM '/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgis.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV HEADER;`